# How to highlight a common header file based on different source module contexts?

Tags: c, eclipse, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-cdt, conditional-compilation

I have a project comprised of several source modules and header files. Two of them (`s1.c`, `s2.c`) `#include` the same header file (`s3.h`). That header file contains conditional compilation construct, based on an externally defined macro:

```
#ifdef ExtMacro
#define IntMacro 1
#else
#define IntMacro 2
#endif
```

Now, `ExtMacro` is defined in `s1.c` before the `#include "s3.h"`, but is *not* defined in `s2.c`.

When opening the header file in the Eclipse editor, the code is parsed for syntax highlighting, and the parts that are excluded from the build are highlighted in gray background.

As you can see, the excluded part of `s3.h` depends on the context of its inclusion. But Eclipse chooses one of the including modules for the purpose of highlighting the header code.

Is there a way to tell Eclipse to highlight the header code in one context or another?

Comment: It's an indexer-related problem. Try messing around with it's settings in *Project Properties->C/C++ General->Indexer*. But I wouldn't be optimistic about it.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the header to the list at `Preferences -> C/C++ -> Indexer -> "Index all variants of specific headers"`, then CDT will index both versions of the header.

When you then open the header by following the #include in `s1.c`, it will show you the version indexed in the context of `s1.c`. When you open it by following the #include in `s2.c`, it will show you the version indexed in the context of `s2.c`.

I don't know of a way to control which version is shown when you open the header without context (e.g. via the Project Explorer).

(Instead of adding the header to the `"Index all variants of specific headers"` list, you could also just check `"Index all header variants"`. However, I don't recommend this, as it is likely to have an adverse impact of the performance of indexing your project.)

Comment: Thanks. That's sounds like the solution to the problem, although almost two years after asking, I honestly don't remember the context of that question 8-). I will try to generate a test case for that in our workspace, to approve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set ExtMacro as Symbol in Paths & Symbols. Then you create two build configurations, one where ExtMacro is defined and one where it is not. Then you set the indexer to re-index, when the configuration changes. With the switch of the configuration the indexer will show the correct context.

Then you likely need to exclude the fixed define in `s1.c` from the indexer. The Eclipse CDT parser generates a preprocessor symbol that you can trigger on and use:

```
#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
#else
#define ExtMacro
#endif
```

This way the symbol ExtMacro is hidden for the CDT parser but not your real compiler and it only picks up the symbol from the build configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting idea, but the actual file is a production code from a project developed by a team of programmers (and I am the only one using Eclipse for development). I do not own that module and would not like to do code changes.

Comment: @ysap You don't have to commit the change and it might work without excluding if you only want to see the `.h` file correctly.

Comment: But then  you'll have to repeat the process whenever you pull changes, no? (or, go through some tedious process of merging or so).

Comment: @ysap You will have to pick the lesser of three evils. There is no perfect method, this is the best answer *hint, hint* you will likely get. For a workplace answer, I would get a candy bar and bribe the programmer of s1.c with it.